# Conditional check with AND and OR is failing

Tags: if-statement, go

I am trying to combine few conditional check

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type ActionType string

const (
    VNFHealthCheck ActionType = "vnf-health-check"
    CollectAlaramAddToReport    ActionType = "write-initial-report"
    CollectResourcesAddCounters ActionType = "abc"
)

func main() {
    var action, operationType interface{}
    action = nil
    operationType = "vnf-health-check"
    if operationType == string(VNFHealthCheck) && action != nil && action.(ActionType) == CollectAlaramAddToReport {
        fmt.Println("Type is ", reflect.TypeOf(action))
    }
}
```

The above code does not print anything as **action != nil** check fails.

But when if condition changes to

```
if operationType == string(VNFHealthCheck) && action != nil && action.(ActionType) == CollectAlaramAddToReport || action.(ActionType) == CollectResourcesAddCounters {
        fmt.Println("Hello, playground", reflect.TypeOf(action))
    }
```

Panic is seen with message
**panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not main.ActionType**

If condition check works fine after adding *()* around OR condition

```
if operationType == string(VNFHealthCheck) && action != nil && (action.(ActionType) == CollectAlaramAddToReport || action.(ActionType) == CollectResourcesAddCounters) {
        fmt.Println("Hello, playground", reflect.TypeOf(action))
    }
```

What could be cause of the behavior.? I couldn't find any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `&&` has higher precedence than `||`

in the first condition,

```golang
operationType == string(VNFHealthCheck) && action != nil && action.(ActionType) == CollectAlaramAddToReport || action.(ActionType) == CollectResourcesAddCounters
```

cause `action` is `nil`, the condition becomes `false || action.(ActionType) == CollectResourcesAddCounters`. the `nil` cast trigger the panic

the second condition becomes `false && (action.(ActionType) == CollectAlaramAddToReport || action.(ActionType) == CollectResourcesAddCounters)`. cause the `false` short circuit the expression, the cast won't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

See the [operator precedence section of the specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operator_precedence).  The `&&` operator has higher precedence than `||`.  The parentheses are required to get the grouping you intended.

A type assertion is not needed when comparing a value to an `interface{}`. If `action` is one of the specified values, then it follows that `action != nil`.  Using these observations, simplify the code to:

```
if operationType == string(VNFHealthCheck) && (action == CollectAlaramAddToReport || action == CollectResourcesAddCounters) {
        fmt.Printf("Hello, playground %T\n", action)
}
```